# How do I select more than 1 framework with jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jsfiddle

How do I actually get jsfiddle to use more than 1 library? I can only seem to get it to use either jquery OR knockout but not both. Yet when I look at other peoples fiddles they dont seem to have this problem. Really annoying dont know why its so diffuclt and no searches on the internet yielded anything!!!

Thanks

Comment: once you have select the js file then under that drop down it will display the nessary js files under that framwork then you can easily select/unselect your wanted ones.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can only assign one framework via the dropdown in the sidebar. If you need to add another framework you need to add a resource using a link to a CDN.

Comment: Should be able to pick the ones you want with checkboxes. How is this different than adding them manually, other than saving me time from tracking down the URLs. I must be misunderstanding the issue then.

Comment: It's no different, it just moves the burden of checking whether the frameworks you're including are compatible from jsfiddle on to the user.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : By that reasoning, shouldn't jsfiddle also not allow bad examples? ;-) Let me deal with any headaches... Thats why I fiddle...

Comment: "It's no different, it just moves the burden of checking whether the frameworks you're including are compatible from jsfiddle on to the user." - The only difference between selecting multiple frameworks with checkboxes and having to go chase down a URL is convenience. It's inconvenient. Plain and simple.

Comment: what do you mean by CDN

Comment: @Prageeth a Content Delivery Network, such as [Google's](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) enables websites to use common versions of libraries which can be cached in the user's browser.

Answer (score 7):

Use this to add another framework. Sample showing knockout cdn

```
$.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js", function(){
    /* Lines of code */
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call getScript, just use the "external resources" section to add other resources.

Comment: yes, just type the CDN address as string in the text box next to the "+" button in the External Resources section, then click the "+" button.